# How to find the standard function equivalent to `foo<-`?

Tags: r

(**NB:** In the title, and throughout this post, I use the adjective "standard" to describe functions that are pre-existing (as opposed to created on-the-fly at runtime) and available by default in a vanilla `R` session, without needing to load additional packages or use package-qualified names.  I'm sure there's a better way to refer to such functions.  Please let me know what it is.)

---

It often happens that the "typical" way to set an item's attribute (at least after it was created) is through an assignment.  E.g. in the case of the `names` attribute, this would look like this:

```
lo4 <- function.returning.list.of.four.items(blah, blah, blah)
names(lo4) <- c('eeny', 'meeny', 'miny', 'moe')
```

(I'll refer to such attributes as "assignment-settable"<sup>1</sup>.)

Alternatively, one can set the attribute's value on-the-fly, using function obtained by appending `<-` to the attribute's name (and quoting the whole thing); e.g.:

```
lo4 <- `names<-`(function.returning.list.of.four.items(blah, blah, blah),
                 c('eeny', 'meeny', 'miny', 'moe'))
```

(For the sake of this question, I'll use the ad-hoc term *computed [attribute] setter* for functions like `` `names<-` `` above.)

It turns out, however, that for *some* (not all!) attributes, there are standard `R` functions that allow setting their values "on the fly"; for example, the `names` attribute, there's the standard `setNames` function:

```
lo4 <- setNames(function.returning.list.of.four.items(blah, blah, blah),
                c('eeny', 'meeny', 'miny', 'moe'))
```

(Again, for the sake of this question, I'll use the ad-hoc term *standard [attribute] setter* for standard attribute-setting functions, like `setNames`.)

The example of `setNames` may encourage the hope that, for any other assignment-settable attribute `foo`, there would be a *standard attribute setter* `setFoo`.  Unfortunately, this does not appear to be the case:

```
m2x2 <- setDim(function.returning.vector.of.four.ints(blah, blah, blah), c(2, 2))
Error: could not find function "setDim"
```

---

My question is: *if* there exists a *standard attribute setter* for some assignment-settable attribute `foo`, is there a systematic way to find its name?

Naively searching the documentation for `foo` is not enough.  For example, `setNames` is not mentioned at all in the documentation for `names`.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Come to think of it, I can't off-hand come up with any attribute in `R` that is not assignment-settable, so maybe the "assignment-settable" descriptor is redundant.</sup>

Comment: `setNames` is the anomaly here. It's a one-off function that's part of the stats package, not base.

Comment: The code for `setNames` is just 2 lines, the first is `names(object) <- nm` and the second returns the resulting object. There is no real advantage to using it, other than perhaps readability.

Comment: `structure(1:10, names=letters[1:10], foo="bar")` also works. And no, imho there are no "standard" attributes which you can set. Since everything is based on the packages used, the methods can have their own definition in their respective packages.